# Chunked polyfill for browsers without Intl support throws an error

Tags: python, reactjs, browser, frontend

So I'm encountering this problem when trying to run my frontend after I set this piece of code for polyfilling the Intl object and its related internationalization features in browsers that do not natively support it. All I know is that if I comment out that code and leave only the render command everything works fine. Can you check if I messed up something since I'm not very familiar with this approach?

```
      
// Chunked polyfill for browsers without Intl support
if (!window.Intl) {
  new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(import('intl'));
  })
    .then(() =>
      Promise.all([
        import('intl/locale-data/jsonp/en')
      ]),
    ) // eslint-disable-line prettier/prettier
    .then(() => render(translationMessages))
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
} else {
  render(translationMessages);
```

This is the thrown error:

```
ERROR in ./app/app.js 112:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (112:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| if (!window.Intl) {
|   new Promise(function (resolve) {
>     resolve(import('intl'));
|   }).then(function () {
|     return Promise.all([import('intl/locale-data/jsonp/en')]);
```

I tried running the frontend headless, headed or with specifying a browser